# Is it possible to change the directory where the modules are copied using GeneXus /Install?

Tags: genexus

Every time **GeneXus /install** is executed, it copy all .OPC files from the modules to the directory %userprofile%.gxmodules, and if there are multiple module versions, it occupies several GB.
Typically, %userprofile% on Windows is located on the c:\ drive.

System administrators are asking if it's possible to move the cache and local module server to a different directory (and a different disk) other than c:.

Answer (score 2):

To change the directory where the module repository is stored in GeneXus, you need to add the following entries to the genexus.exe.config file.

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="UserAppDataPath" value="C:\SomePath\Inst1\UserAppData" />
</appSettings>
```

You can also centralize the temporary files that GeneXus needs to function by adding the following entry to the genexus.exe.config file.

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="ProgramDataPath" value="C:\SomePath\Inst1\ProgramData" />
</appSettings>
```

With these configurations, you can share the module repository among multiple users (useful for build machines) and also manage multiple installations of different upgrades of the same GeneXus version without the fear of compatibility issues caused by sharing files between different versions.